# Facebook disabled my account; can I legally force them to restore it?

Tags: contract-law, internet, terms-of-service

I was trying to sell adult goods on facebook as I sold other kind of products as usual to multiple facebook communities. I happened to forget nudity was forbidden on facebook. But the package contained a naked woman.

I made a mistake unintentionally. But I got my account disabled instantly. I am not able to login to my account. I tried to appeal to FB many time to recover my account. But they refused to do so.

This has made a huge loss to me as I have got so many personal data (including pictures and videos), so many friends' connection, and so many chat records(including some business details) in the server. I lost everything by their single act.

Is there any legal way to force facebook return my person data?

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: In some jurisdictions, privacy laws might give you the right to receive a data dump of your personal data if Facebook did not hard-delete it yet (and they didn't, because they are Facebook). That won't restore your account, but might allow you to salvage the personal data. But you didn't mention where you are, so we can not tell you if those privacy laws are applicable.

Answer (score 3):

You violated Facebook's [Terms of Service](https://www.facebook.com/terms.php), and it's entirely within your contractual agreement with them for them to close your account. You agreed to abide by the contract you "clicked through" when you signed up and opened a Facebook account.

They didn't break any laws when you broke your contract with them. You clearly broke the contract by violating the TOS. They are not breaking any laws by not restoring your account.

What you see as the value of your personal or business data doesn't really mean anything; it was your choice to use Facebook in the first place, and your mistake to break the TOS.

You could try hiring a lawyer to make a case that you see a difference between the personal data you want to retrieve and the business data that caused the violation, but that's up to you; Facebook is under no legal obligation (this *could* be different, according to your jurisdiction and national laws) to restore any or all access to your account or data, but it's possible they could be persuaded.